# Python: Get caret position

Tags: python, position, pywin32, caret

I'm trying to get the caret position in Python. I tried using `win32gui.GetCaretPos()` but it always returns 0,0.

Do you have any ideas how to make it work?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Please post your code to make it a little bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the caret is in a window created by another thread, you need to call [`AttachThreadInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Assuming you want the caret of the foreground window, you can get to it like this:

```
import win32gui
import win32process
import win32api

fg_win = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
fg_thread, fg_process = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(fg_win)
current_thread = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()
win32process.AttachThreadInput(current_thread, fg_thread, True)
try:
    print win32gui.GetCaretPos()
finally:
    win32process.AttachThreadInput(current_thread, fg_thread, False) #detach
```

Comment: works in all editor... except the one that I need :-) Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: What would be an efficient way of hooking into or polling for changes in active window constantly?

Comment: @koral Better to start a new question especially that this one is closed.