# Finding the caret location in Windows with Python 3

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32, win32gui

My goal is to display a tooltip wherever the user is typing. To do this, I need to find the location of the caret (the place where the user is typing). I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.8. Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724360/python-get-caret-position), I tried the following code:

```
import win32gui
import win32process
import win32api

fg_win = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
fg_thread, fg_process = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(fg_win)
current_thread = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()
win32process.AttachThreadInput(current_thread, fg_thread, True)
try:
    print(win32gui.GetCaretPos())
finally:
    win32process.AttachThreadInput(current_thread, fg_thread, False) #detach
```

The code prints 0,0 regardless of where the caret actually is. How can can I get the location of the caret on the screen?

Comment: There is no supported way to use `AttachThreadInput` reliably from Python. Not much of a loss, since it's not part of your solution anyway. Use [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/winevents-infrastructure) instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, not all carets in the edit box cannot be read. [`GetCaretPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcaretpos) can only get the caret in the standard edit box.

So you can get caret in standard edit box like notepad, wordpad, etc., like this:

[image]

And now most of the edit boxes are not standard edit boxes, but rich text boxes. You can refer to [`EM_POSFROMCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-posfromchar) to learn how to get the caret position in the rich text box, but the message is used in different ways depending on the version of the rich text box.

> **Parameters**
>
> wParam
>
> **Rich Edit 1.0 and 3.0:** A pointer to a POINTL structure that receives the client area coordinates of the character. The coordinates are in screen units and are relative to the upper-left corner of the control's client area.
>
> **Edit controls and Rich Edit 2.0:** The zero-based index of the character.
>
> lParam
>
> **Rich Edit 1.0 and 3.0:** The zero-based index of the character.
>
> **Edit controls and Rich Edit 2.0:** This parameter is not used.
>
> Return value
>
> **Rich Edit 1.0 and 3.0:** The return value is not used.
>
> **Edit controls and Rich Edit 2.0:** The return value contains the client area coordinates of the character. The LOWORD contains the horizontal coordinate and the HIWORD contains the vertical coordinate.

You can use [`GetClassName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassname) to get the classname, distinguish the version of richedit according to the classname, and send the message.

More references:[About Rich Edit Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-rich-edit-controls), [Get version of rich edit library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397734/get-version-of-rich-edit-library)